# Bash for loop without arguments

Tags: bash

Could someone please clarify why the following code is valid in bash and what, if any, is the effect?

```sh
for value ; do
  echo $value
done
```

As far as I can tell, bash simply ignores this code, but I do not see why it would not raise a syntax error or something?

Comment: in your terminal run `help for` and try https://shellcheck.net for validating shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's ok, I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jetchisel pointed out, we can run `help for` in our shell to see the docstring for the `for` command.

```
$ help for
for: for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
    Execute commands for each member in a list.
    
    The `for' loop executes a sequence of commands for each member in a
    list of items.  If `in WORDS ...;' is not present, then `in "$@"' is
    assumed.  For each element in WORDS, NAME is set to that element, and
    the COMMANDS are executed.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed.
```

The part that I did not know is highlighted below for emphasis:

> [...] **If `in WORDS ...;' is not present, then `in "$@"' is assumed.** [...]